# Tui Calendar all day panel event not expanding

Tags: extjs, tui-calendar

I'm working on a bug, we used Tui calendar and on calendar events, the scroll bar is disabled/grayed out. I was able to enable the scroll bar by adjusting the height but when I click on the grid footer button which is supposed to view the hidden events, an arrow up is displayed but not the hidden events. Hoping someone in this community can help. Here is a screenshot (assuming there are calendar events here and there are also hidden events. I also can't see any solutions on the internet. Thank you in advance for your help, it will be very much appreciated.

[image]